# Is Cloudinary API secure if I do the following

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cloudinary

I am using the base api url below like in many examples ..https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/name.
But if I use dotenv to hide the name and to hide the upload preset like below then will that keep my api secure or will people be able to find it from the img urls that are returned when an image is uploaded.

formData.append('upload_preset', process.env.REACT_APP_UPLOAD_PRESET);
      `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUD_NAME}/image/upload`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowing uploads from client-side code and are sending them from the client to Cloudinary directly, users will always be able to see the cloud name and upload preset name you use, if not easily in your app's source, then certainly via a proxy or other debug tools.

However, that's expected, and is the reason for using the unsigned upload option: unsigned uploads to allow you to perform uploads in cases where the client can't authenticate itself with a server component by using the upload preset you specify - what happens to the uploaded files is determined by the pre-configured options in the upload preset so you can name them a certain way, put them in a specific folder, add tags, edit the images via resizing or other transformations before they're saved, etc.

If you don't want to expose the cloud name or upload preset name, you'll need to pass the files to a server endpoint you control, and then upload them to Cloudinary from there, which would put you in the same basic situation where the client code has the ability to upload files without authentication [or using authentication your users can see and can copy], although then it would be the endpoint on your server allowing that rather than Cloudinary's /v1_1/